# Overwrite image in php while uploading

Tags: php, image

I want to know that how  can I overwrite images when they uploaded to server in php. For example I uploaded a photo to a folder as soon as I upload another image it will take place of previous image. Image name is not same it may differ. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the previous image before uploading the new one using:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'img/img.jpg';
unlink($path);
```

This code basically assigns the path of the image to **$path** and deletes the image using **unlink($path);**